# Some python tutorials for Windows use "py -3" to invoke Python. It does not work for me

Tags: python, windows

I installed python 3.8 from the Windows store. Typing "python" works.  Why does py -3  not work for me?  I re-did all the steps in the main tutorial I was following.

It says "py" is not found as any of a bunch of things it could be.

Comment: You need to install the `py.exe launcher`. See https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Comment: Thanks @Booboo.  The tutorials never mentioned the launcher.

Comment: I tried that and it worked. Yay!!  For anyone still confused, the Python installer has an option to install the "launcher".  Leave it checked, because that's the "py" in question.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no answer to this question (It is in the comments)

Refer to [this page for the source](https://spapas.github.io/2017/12/20/python-2-3-windows/) of this information

Firstly I am installing Python 2.X and selecting:

- Install for all users
- Install to default folder
- Press next to following screen (install default customizations). This won’t add the python.exe of Python 2.X to path

Next to install Python 3.X:

- Make sure to click “Install launcher for all users (recommended)”
- Also check “Add Python 3.6to PATH” (to add the Python 3.X executable to path)
- Then just click “Install Now” (this will put Python 3.X to c:)

---

To use / test using :

```
py -3 
py -2
```

This should launch python 3 and 2 respectively

---

- [Link to start](https://www.python.org/downloads/)